# Cloudera - CCP Data Engineer Certification ( DE575)

Tags: cloudera

Is it possible to clear the CCP Data Engineer certification(DE575) by only mastering Hive, Sqoop, Flume and Oozie? If not what else would be needed?

FYI - I don't have a cloudera license to post this question in cloudera community.

Thanks
Max

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: any idea where should i post this?

Comment: Interisting question. Would have helped me as well.